# How to use force_update in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, customization, insert-update

```
a = Article(title="New Article", slug="new-article")
a.save()
print a
```

OUTPUT

`New Article`

How I update only `title` using force_update.

Comment: You are not updating, you are creating a new record.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
a = Article(title="New Article")
a.save(force_insert=True)
print a


New Article
a.title = "Better Title"
a.save(force_update=True)
print a
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for this one, Thanks [@gretal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9127224/gretal)

Answer (score 0):

**Models.py :**

```
class Article(models.Model):   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slugfield ...
```

**Views.py:**

```
#Create a model instance
a = Article(title="New Article", slug="new-article")
a.save()
#Article object created



#To update an existing article object first select that object by,
article_to_be_updated = Article.objects.get(id = #article's id)



#now update the selected articles field and then save it by,
article_to_be_updated.title = "updated title"
article_to_be_updated.save()
#updated only the title and reflected changes to DB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the record with the given slug, you can do this with:

```
Article.objects.filter(slug='new-article').update(title='New Article')
```